# Rest Api routes only working for GET in production

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, passenger

I'm running a node.js rest api with Express v4. All the routes work as expected via localhost debug. But on my server, they don't. **The only thing that differs, is that the port listening is done by Phusion Passenger on the server** (I can't change that). Here's my app.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  helmet = require('helmet'),
  http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());

app.use('/', require('./api/routes'));

var server = http.createServer(app);
var port = 'passenger'; // 3000 on localhost
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening ' + port);
});
```

Here's a my routes.js that works on local debug, but won't on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('test get works !');
  res.end('test get works!');
});

router.post('/api/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('test post works !');
  res.end('test post works!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here are the logs for localhost (successful routing):

```
20180107_192254 | /api/test
20180107_192254 | { get: true } 
20180107_192254 | test get works ! 

20180107_192350 | /api/test
20180107_192350 | { post: true }
20180107_192350 | test post works !
```

The log file of the same process, but done via the remote server (I'm always redirected to the first route, and req.method is always GET). While the 'req.route.path' is the always the good one, it never goes into the expected function:

```
20180107_192757 | /api/test
20180107_192757 | { get: true }
20180107_192757 | test get works ! 

20180107_192759 | /api/test
20180107_192759 | { get: true }
20180107_192759 | test get works !
```

Do you know if I have to update something somewhere (maybe .htaccess, or in the js code)? I couldn't find anything on both the Phusion and the Express doc.

**EDIT:**

I replace the express router with a direct use of route by the app and it doesn't work.

But I noticed something:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('test get works !');
  res.end('test get works!');
});

router.post('/api/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('test post works !');
  res.end('test post works!');
});

router.get('/api/otherTest', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('other test get works !');
  res.end('other test get works!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here, I can go the the first and the third routes. In fact, all GET routes work (and only them). If I do this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/api/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route.path);
  console.log(req.route.methods);
  console.log('test post works !');
  res.end('test post works!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I get nothing.

Comment: Please, describe a little bit more about ports case. What do you mean, another port?
As I understand, the code you wrote on your local machine you just upload to the server. Or you make any corrections before uploading?

Comment: This is the same code on both sides. Except for the app.js: on my machine it is specified "server.listen('3000')" whereas on the server I have to set it to "server.listen('passenger')".

I think that because of Passenger, Express is doing weird stuff about the routing, but I can be wrong.

Comment: Haven't seen this before. I suggest adding some middlewares to your app using `app.use()` and how Passenger delegate request to your app. 
Also, try to add a little bit more code. Show the way you define Express app. And, finally, I suggest reading in docs what version of Express is supported by Passenger, because, Express 4.0 comes with the new Router and in v5 they just returned the implementation from v3. So this can be a problem. Try to play with it. I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: Hum... maybe it's a version issue, yes, I didn't think about that. I'll check and edit my post tonight. Thank you.

Comment: So, to check it at first, just get rid of Router and add all your routes to the app itself, using this way `app.get()` `app.post()`

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't the method used to send said requests?

Comment: @Yevhenii Herasymchuk: I updated my post and the title.

Comment: @Kevin B: I can't see why. It works on  debug on my machine. Shit hits the fan when I request remotely.

Comment: Have you done my suggestions? Get rid of  `express.Router()` and define all routes to the app itself http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: And after your UPDATE I guess you need to debug and search for mistakes in URI you use (if your GET methods work like should). Try to log in every step. 
Also, what tool do you use when test with POST, what error do you get for the POST request?

Comment: @Yevhenii Herasymchuk: yes I got rid of the router, but nothing changed. I use Postman to test my api. When I post, I get no error if I have a GET method on the same route. But I get a "cannot get 'path'" if I only have a POST method associated with the route. So it's like the http server translates every request as GET requests...

Comment: But you have to see something in Postman after POST request. At least "No response" or something like that. Interesting issue, but I'm sure the problem is so easy to solve. 
Try to change the version of Express (clean `npm_modules/` and reinstall all). Or if you can, try to log every step of the request.

Comment: @Yevhenii Herasymchuk: I updated my post. There is a actually a 'res.end('')' at the end of each function in my actual api. So that's what I get in postman. I'll try to give you more when I'll be home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figure it out: my website is rerouting all *http://* traffic to *https://*  traffic, and all requests (GET, POST, PUT,...) sent through *http://* are somehow transformed to GET requests.

They are all correct via *https://*.

I don't know why this is happening, but feel free to give more details about this issue if you do! I'll update when I find out.